# Where on Stack Exchange should I ask a question about online video streaming?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to figure out how some sites are able to upload videos to Google and embed them for online video streaming. I was going to ask on Stack Overflow but I don't know if this would be a programming question or not. When I say upload to Google Video I'm talking more along the lines of how pirate sites are able to exploit Google into hosting the content even though it's against copyright. Examples are on sites like 123movies(.)to which use video streams that are coming from Google.

Comment: I don't think asking about the illegal use of google would be on topic anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure why this gets so much negative reception. Site recommendation questions are on-topic and asking questions about dubious practices can be helpful if you're in the market for developing counter measures. Don't mix-up your (dis)-like of the actual question with the merits of the meta one.

Comment: @rene if a question is not useful, how can it be useful to ask where such question should be asked? ;-) (besides, I find this meta-question rather unclear, which is a reason enough to vote)

Comment: @JanDvorak fair enough

Comment: @Liam [law.stackexchange](http://law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular question seems overly broad and would require a lot to explain as they have to assume you're somewhat new to the topic. Given that fact I'm pretty sure none of the sites within the Stack Exchange network will take that question.

If that is everything you have you better look for other options around the web, Quora, reddit and more traditional forums spring to mind.

If you do want to make an serious effort to bring your question down to something that might be in scope consider creating such an pirating site yourself on a small scale. Research the possible software stacks you could use, how you would deliver content, try the Google hosting your self.

If you take notes of things that you stumble into and see if you can either resolve them and if not ask a specific, detailed question about that. This might be related to a programming issue, that could go on Stack Overflow, or how a specific client responds to video content, this could go on Super User, or for specific hosting options Web Masters might be a good place. You should always check [What is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for any site you're thinking of posting on.

On your journey while working on your prototype of a site you'll discover security related topics that might have answers on Information Security, or about licenses on Law etc.

**tl;dr** For overly broad questions the SE network is not a good fit as the Q/A model doesn't really cope well with those type of questions. If making the question specific is not possible, try anywhere else on the internet.